# Newtonsoft JSON - create JArray in JArray

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net

I am trying to create JSON array using Newtonsoft JSON API but its giving me error. I want to achieve structure like

```
[

    {
        "id":"26",
        "appsurvey":"1",
        "fk_curriculumid":"70",
        "status":"Completed",
        "lastaccessedon":"2014-06-20 09:18:54",
        "questions":[
            {
                "feedback":"6",
                "questionid":"1"
            },
            {
                "feedback":"8",
                "questionid":"2"
            },
            {
                "feedback":"1",
                "questionid":"3"
            }
        ],
        "fk_clientid":"24",
        "learnerid":"260"
    }

]
```

I want ot add questions array for multiple time but it is giving me error 
`Can not add property questions to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object.`

Here is my code:

```
JArray surveytrackingA = new JArray();
/*code to add
[

    {"id":"26",
        "appsurvey":"1",
        "fk_curriculumid":"70",
        "status":"Completed",
        "lastaccessedon":"2014-06-20 09:18:54"}]
*/
for (int i = 0; i < surveytrackingA.Count; i++)
{

    JObject surveytrackD = (JObject)surveytrackingA[i];
    string queryOne = "select * from table101 where fk_curriculumid='"
            + surveytrackD["fk_curriculumid"].ToString()
            + "' and fk_surveyid='"
            + surveytrackD["appsurvey"].ToString() + "'";

    JArray questionsA = new JArray();

    using (var stmt = await App.localDB.PrepareStatementAsync(queryOne))
    {
        while (await stmt.StepAsync())
        {
            JObject questionD = new JObject();
            questionD.Add("questionid", stmt.GetTextAt(5));
            questionD.Add("feedback", stmt.GetTextAt(6));
            questionsA.Add(questionD);
        }
    }                    
    surveytrackD.Add("questions", questionsA); /*error occurred here when second question array is getting inserted in surveyTrackD*/
    surveytrackingA.Add(surveytrackD);
}
```

Can anyone please correct me. Thanks in advance.

**Update**:
surveytrackD have the json data,

```
{
  "fk_clientid": "24",
  "learnerid": "260",
  "appsurvey": "1",
  "id": "26",
  "fk_curriculumid": "70",
  "status": "completed",
  "lastaccessedon": "2014-06-20 09:18:54"
}
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting your code when you post a question. I've fixed this one now, but use the preview before you post to check that you don't have pointless indentation etc. Also, you should use parameterized SQL. That's off the topic of the question, of course.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem? Get rid of anything that isn't required, and hard-code any data you need. I can't see anything immediately wrong, but it'll be a lot easier to fix it if I can tinker with it for myself.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and correcting me. I have just put structure that I need to achieve and the code by which I am getting this. But at time of adding the same array (questions) I am getting error. I just want to figure out why I am facing this?

Comment: And as I say, it'll be easier for us to be able to figure out what's wrong if you take some time to transform your current code into a self-contained program which demonstrates the same failure, just using hard-coded data. Oh, and tell us where the exception is thrown. I *suspect* it's at `surveytrack.Add("questions", questionsA)` but we can't tell. What's in `surveytrackD` at the start of the loop? Does that already *have* a `questions` property, for example? (If so, that would explain it.)

Comment: the above json format you can refer for hardcoded data, it is same json format I am getting in Android, and same I am implementing in Windows Phone.

Comment: That's the data you want as the result. While I *could* take your program and try to construct one with that data and reproduce the problem, it's a better idea for you to do this yourself. a) you're the one requesting help; you should make it as easy to help you as possible. b) it's good practice at diagnosing issues. c) you may well find the answer while you're doing it anyway. If you're not willing to put in the time to provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem, why should anyone else put in the time to help you?

Comment: (And you haven't answered the question about what's already in `surveytrackD` at the start of the loop. We can't possibly know that based on what's in your post.)

Comment: Update the question for `surveytrackD` data.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result (JArray in JArray) using regular C# classes and at the end serialize to JSon.

I posted a sample in [Github](https://github.com/berXpert/SurveyTrack); here a fragment of the code that produces your expected output:

```
        var Surveys = new List<SurveytrackD>();

        Surveys.Add( new SurveytrackD { id = "26", appsurvey = "1", fk_curriculumid = "70", status = "Completed", learnerid = "240"  } );
        Surveys.Add( new SurveytrackD { id = "27", appsurvey = "1", fk_curriculumid = "71", status = "Completed", learnerid = "241" });


        foreach (var survey in Surveys)
        {
            survey.questions = new List<Question>();

            survey.questions.Add(new Question { questionid = "1", feedback = "0" });
            survey.questions.Add(new Question { questionid = "2", feedback = "1" });
        }

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Surveys, Formatting.Indented);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The output is:

```
[
  {
    "fk_clientid": null,
    "learnerid": "240",
    "appsurvey": "1",
    "id": "26",
    "fk_curriculumid": "70",
    "status": "Completed",
    "lastaccessedon": null,
    "questions": [
      {
        "feedback": "0",
        "questionid": "1"
      },
      {
        "feedback": "1",
        "questionid": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "fk_clientid": null,
    "learnerid": "241",
    "appsurvey": "1",
    "id": "27",
    "fk_curriculumid": "71",
    "status": "Completed",
    "lastaccessedon": null,
    "questions": [
      {
        "feedback": "0",
        "questionid": "1"
      },
      {
        "feedback": "1",
        "questionid": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```